# How to find out which links of website posted on Twitter

Tags: web-crawlers, links, backlinks, twitter, user-agent

I recenlty noticed many requests from `Twitterbot` user agent in my website's logs which I believe it doesn't crawl by itself unless someone is posting links of my website on Twitter. These posts might be abusive and harm our reputation.

So, I wish to find out which links of my website has been posted on Twitter. With the URL shortener services such us bit.ly and goo.gl, I find it hard to search directly for the links. Is there any way to trace that? I'd appreciate it if anyone could enlighten me with an answer.

Comment: Someone will correct me if i am wrong, but I would say it is impossible.  The shortened URLs are random, how are you going to search for such a thing?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, twitter treats short urls as original url, so example.com/url is the same as bit.ly/190. There is no reverse method, you'll have to go through your entire url sets and see how many shares per url or not. if that makes sense.

Comment: This may sound obvious and do not mean any insult, but I tend to search in the search textbox on the Twitter site for my domain name without the TLD. It may not get everything, but so far I think it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter search box is capable of tracking even inside url shortened links. So just put your domain name in the search box and see the results. But it's limited to past 7 days.

If you use analytics software, you can see destination page of people coming from twitter. Just go to Social->Twitter in acquisition, then add as secondary dimension "destination urls" (remember only last 7 days) and put them on twitter or topsy http://topsy.com/.

If that's so important, I suggest to use also a social media monitoring tool and google alert.